# Purpose of comma

Tags: grammar

> It must know that even if it is able to forge an agreed
> strategy and act as a cohesive coalition, there is hardly
> any surety that it will achieve its principal objective of
> forcing the Imran Khan government from power.

What is the purpose/function of a comma which is after coalition in this sentence?

Comment: As I parse this, the comma after "coalition" should be paired with a comma before "even".

Comment: I took this sentence from a newspaper. There was no comma before "even" in the newspaper article.